# Paginate child entity in edit page sonata admin Bundle

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to paginate a child entity embedded within a parent entity. The child entity is instance of array collection.

I am displaying this using `sonata_type_collection` as below:

```
$formMapper->add('earningRules', 'sonata_type_collection', array(                                            
    'type_options' => array('delete' => FALSE),
    'edit' => 'inline',
    'inline' => 'table',
    'sortable' => 'position',
));
```

How can I paginate this on my edit page?